# g++ makefile, include error, no such file or directory

Tags: c++, include, makefile, g++, include-path

I am trying to include the following headers:

```
#include <libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_oarchive.hpp>
```

These files are located in a path like:

```
/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0/libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp
```

In my Makefile, I have added:

```
-I/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0/libs
```

However, when I compile, I get the error messages like:

```
error: libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?  I am also including boost libraries like

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
```

However, to get those, it is sufficient to do in my Makefile:

```
-I/usr/include/boost
```

Why doesn't this work for the headers in the other location?  How should I change my Makefile?  The first statement current looks like this:

```
test: test.o 
    g++ -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -L/usr/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams -lz -I/usr/include/boost -I/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0/libs -o test test.o
```

Comment: g++ makes a distinction between `#include <>` and `#include ""` for what paths it searches. Can't recall the details right off, but that is what is happening...

Comment: #include <> should be the correct one to use right here.

Comment: @dmckee, that's nothing to do with it. `#include ""` searches the current directory first, then behaves identically to `#include <>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get

```
#include <libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp>
```

from directory

```
/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0/libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp
```

your Makefile needs

```
-I/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0
```

Notice that I omitted the `/libs` from the end. That's because your `#include` directive already lists that directory.

---

As for your second example, is the file you want at this location:

```
/usr/include/boost/boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp
                   ^^^^^ (repeated boost here)
```

If not g++ is likely defaulting to `/usr/include` as the search space for

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
```

Ie., your

```
-I/usr/include/boost
```

is useless to the compiler.

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work even after I removed libs from the end of the -I path, same error is still showing up. Also -I/usr/include/boost is probably not necessary, I removed it and it didn't seem to change anything. If it matters, #include <libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp> is in a header file that is included in my top level .cpp file.

Comment: @user788171 Thinking of it of some more, it's really odd that you're including a header from the *example* directory. Is what you actually want in `/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0/include/serialization/...`? I notice the [example file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/serialization/example/portable_binary_iarchive.hpp) includes other Boost headers, which is what you should really be doing.

Comment: Yea, I actually want to use the headers in example, I'm making a derived class based off of the one in the example.

Comment: @user788171 If you really have your heart set on using the example file like that, all I can advise is to make sure you've spelt your path correctly. My above answer should work if the file is in that directory.

Comment: @user788171, did you remove `libs` or `/libs`?

Comment: @Beta, that's irrelevant, the result would be the same.

Comment: @user788171, if the suggestion doesn't work then either you didn't do it right or the error you're getting now is actually slightly different. For those files you probably want to simply `#include <portable_binary_iarchive.hpp>` and then use `-I/home/nobody/boost_1_45_0/libs/serialization/example/`, there's no benefit to having that path in the `#include` directive, it just makes it harder to move the files and include them in a different location